# Calculate the combined confidence interval of proportions in metafor package?

Tags: r

Consider the code below:

```
library(metafor)
dat <- escalc(measure="PR", xi=dpos+cpos, ni=dpos+dneg+cpos+cneg, data=data)
res <- rma(yi, vi, data = dat, method="PM")
```

The formulation of xi and ni is proposed by the researcher and is sort of a proportion. The combined confidence interval has an upper limit which is greater than all the proportions of studies. I know that that there is nothing wrong with this result, but just need the exact relations for calculating the combined confidence interval to show the result is correct.

Comment: What do you mean by "the exact relations"?

Comment: I mean to find the confidence interval by hand and show that it gives the same result of the package.

Comment: With ``method="PM"`` you are using an iterative algorithm. You want to do this by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with the PropCIs package?

```
library(PropCIs)
Exact=exactci(x=data$dpos+data$cpos,n=data$dpos+data$dneg+data$cpos+data$cneg)
```

You can see them that way. But you can extract them with

```
Inferior=Exact[[1]][1]
Superior=Exact[[1]][2]
```

Hope it works for you